# MySQL Event does not run

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1, mysql-5

i am running `mysql 5.1.41` that came bundled with `xampp` on windows. the problem is that the event doesnt run automatically even when the `event scheduler` is `ON`. i have a table named `ta_table` using `innodb engine` and it has 4 fields one of which is `ti_time` with a `timestamp` type with default value of `current timestamp`. this field `ti_time` is given the value of timestamp at which the row is inserted. now i want to delete all rows which are 2 hours old from the table `ta_table` so i created an event
the event looks like this

```
CREATE EVENT ev ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS 2011-07-17 14:54:52 ENABLE 
    DO
    begin
    delete from ta_table where timestampdiff(minute,ti_time,now())>120;
    end
```

now this event should delete any rows with `ti_time` field greater than 2 hours(120 minutes). when i execute this query

```
delete from ta_table where timestampdiff(minute,ti_time,now())>120;
```

it works. it deletes the rows older than 2 hours. which means my query is correct but the event is not running. my event scheduler is running which i confirmed by `show processlist`
and it shows 2 preocesses root and event scheduler. 
the `state` of the event scheduler is `waiting for next activation`. 
when i ran this query

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE event_name = 'ev'
```

it gives result as

```
status = enabled
last executed=2011-07-18 02:36:38
```

but when i see the table `ta_table` the records are not deleted? whats wrong with this?

### Edit:

As of RolandoMySQLDBA's suggestion i upgraded mysql 5.1.14 to mysql 5.5 but the event still fails

Comment: can i assume the 'delete from table' query that you said works is a type (should be delete from ta_table?) Also, are there any errors in your mysql error log?

Comment: @DTest: no there are no errors. no `retcode=0`

Comment: @DTest: ya it is `delete from  ta_table`. thanks for pointing out

Comment: @lovesh : Is this problem solved ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA no its not solved. i just removed a "printing mistake"

Comment: @lovesh Can you update the question with the entire output of this query: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME='ev'\G`

Comment: @lovesh I added the sample script I showed you in the chat room to my answer and for all to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some real digging in the bug list for event scheduler issues.

[It seems that a certain time calculation for the event scheduler was not portable](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50087). This bug was fixed as of MySQL 5.1.48 (Fixed June 2, 2010).

[There was a past issue about SHOW EVENTS not getting events from the correct database](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41907). This bug was fixed as of MySQL 5.1.57 (Fixed May 5, 2011).

[The latest scheduler bug was fixed July 5, 2011 in MySQL 5.1.58](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61005)

You are using MySQL 5.1.41. [You may want to upgrade to the latest version of MySQL 5.1 which is 5.1.58](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads). No scheduler bugs exists as of today.

CAVEAT

On another note, I would change the SQL query to not only do less work

Instead of your DELETE query:

```
delete from ta_table where timestampdiff(minute,ti_time,now())>120;
```

Restructure it as follows:

```
delete from ta_table where ti_time < (now() - interval 2 hour);
```

Your DELETE will calculate against every row in the table. This new DELETE stops short when comparing ti_time against a time value  (now() - interval 2 hour) instead of computing timestampdiff on every row.

Make sure ti_time is indexed. If not, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE ta_table ADD INDEX (ti_time);
```

Assuming the table is MyISAM, you may also want to periodically shrink the table every month like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ta_table ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I hope this information helps !!!

**UPDATE 2011-07-19 08:00 EDT**

From the last chat room session lovesh and I had, here is the example I ran to create the event on my PC running MySQL 5.5.12:

```
drop database lovesh;
create database lovesh;
use lovesh
create table mydata (id int not null auto_increment primary key,ti_time timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp) ENGINE=MyISAM;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lovesh`.`LoadMyData` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `lovesh`.`LoadMyData` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE NDX INT;
    SET NDX = 0;
    WHILE NDX < 100 DO
        INSERT INTO mydata (ti_time) VALUES (NOW() - INTERVAL CEILING(14400*RAND()) SECOND);
    SET NDX = NDX + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
show create table mydata\G
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE LoadMyData\G
CALL lovesh.LoadMyData();
CREATE TABLE ta_table LIKE mydata;
ALTER TABLE ta_table DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO ta_table SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM mydata;
ALTER TABLE ta_table ENABLE KEYS;
CREATE EVENT ev
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE
      STARTS (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
    DO
      DELETE FROM ta_table WHERE ti_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ta_table;
SELECT SLEEP(62);
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ta_table;
```

This worked for me when ta_table was MyISAM. It just kept running using InnoDB. This may be the sticking point.

Comment: He may run into issues with upgrading the MySQL for the WAMP install that he's using. Just a comment.

Comment: @jcolebrand : I hope MySQL 5.1.58 would be OK to upgrade to since there are no major changes to the mysql schema and metadata layout from 5.1.x to a more recent 5.1.x. Personally, I have gotten away with upgrading MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 in WAMP using great care.

Comment: I added a link to the MySQL 5.1 downloads to my answer

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA i have mysql 5.5 setup but i am unsure of installing it as things like phpMyAdmin will not work since it came bundled with xampp

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA i dont get ur point with changing the sql query. i think in both the cases(your and mine) the delete query is calculating differnce of two values and comparing them with a value. is there any way i can check that which query is more efficient

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation. its really awesome to see people taking pains to help others

Comment: @lovesh Were you able to upgrade 5.1.57 or higher to see if that fixes the Event issue?

Comment: @lovesh Rolando explained how the new DELETE would be more efficient (now()-interval 2 hour) only has to be calculated once by the parser. the timestampdiff() function must be calculated for each row, because it requires that row's 'ti_time' to be used in calculation.

Comment: @DTest i upgraded to 5.5 but the event is not yet running

Comment: @DTest thanks for explaining the efficiency issue

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: hey that worked at my system too when when i changed engine to myisam

Answer (score 3):

I believe your event must be defined using fully qualified schema and tablename:

> In MySQL 5.1.6, any table referenced in an event's action statement must be fully qualified with the name of the schema in which it occurs (that is, as schema_name.table_name).

Reference: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/mysql-refman/events.html#events-limitations-restrictions

So your query in the EVENT should be redefined (using Rolando's improved delete query):

```
DELETE FROM `ta_db`.`ta_table` WHERE ti_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
```