# Prevent users deleting more than a certain number of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

The problem:

- I have a table with rows, nothing special about it
- When a database user removes a row, it should increment a number
- A database user is only allowed to remove 3 rows max in the table
- A database administrator should be able to add more "remove tokens" to a database user

I know I should have a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger to see if the user can remove a row, and an `AFTER DELETE` trigger to increase the number of rows deleted by the user.

How should I store the info about how many rows a database user has removed from that specific table, and how do I allow a database admin to add more "remove tokens" to the user.

I thought of creating a table to store this, but I wonder if there are different ways to do it without a table? This might sound like a weird question, but I'm just trying to figure out how more advanced stuff works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this kind of granularity, you need to have a rather elaborate setup.

I was thinking of suggesting several things

## SUGGESTION #1 : Use Stored Procedure for Specialized DML

Having to micromanage the number of DELETEs per user to mitigate DML should not become a server-centric function for DELETEs against a specific table. That should remain an application-centric function. Therefore, create a Stored Procedure that can manage the number of DELETEs.

## SUGGESTION #2 : Use the BLACKHOLE storage engine

Any audit trail of DELETEs using a real table can create a localized disk bottleneck that would be a little clumsy to throttle. If the audit trail was recorded in a BLACKHOLE table, that would significantly reduce any disk I/O issues that would otherwise rear its ugly. If you write to a BLACKHOLE table, where would the audit trail data be written? That's leads up to...

## SUGGESTION #3 : Use MySQL Replication

How would MySQL Replication help? Suppose the table is called `mydb.audittrail`. If the `mydb.audittrail` uses BLACKHOLE on the Prod Server, it could replicate to a Slave that that has `mydb.audittrail` as MyISAM. That would be the location of the actual audit data. The only drawback would be added disk I/O for writing audit trail info to the binary logs. You can further reduce that by having the binary logs stored on SSD or a RAM disk.

Please see my answer to [Is it normal to use many Triggers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/is-it-normal-to-use-many-triggers/16184#16184)  for further info on this concept of audit trail recording with the BLACKHOLE Storage Engine and MySQL Replication.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll gonna look into it and chose what I think fits me best right now. Disk I/O right now isn't a problem, it isn't any production database, The database would only contain a couple of tables and some dozen rows, and I'm only doing this to learn, but yeah it's good to keep in mind when doing something real.