# To trigger or not to trigger- That is the question

Tags: mysql, delete

I have a mysql table that tracks page views. Each row includes a date stamp. I want to remove all rows that are over 30 days old on a regular basis. Could, or should, I trigger an action on each insertion of a new row that would delete the rows that are over 30 days old? Or would I be better off adding a separate delete action along with each new insertion?

Comment: Bleh! Do you have any kind of job scheduling system? Just run that once nightly or during a down time and delete the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want a trigger to micromanage such deletions. I have an old post where I created a MySQL Event to delete rows for you ([MySQL Event does not run](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/mysql-event-does-not-run/3911#3911))

Here is an event to delete data older that 30 days every hour starting from midnight tonight

```
USE mydata
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT delete_30_day_old_data
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR
  STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM mytable WHERE datetime_column < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I will be totally independent of any triggers

Of course, you must enable the event_scheduler

First, add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=ON
```

Then, login to mysql as root and run

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON';
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: @EdHeal The event is just an example. You could make it `EVERY 1 DAY` instead of `EVERY 1 HOUR` or whatever schedule is appropriate.

Comment: I agree - personally I would do it once a week and archive it somewhere

Comment: Rowland, thanks for the reply. I maybe should have mentioned that I have 1200 of these tables,  one for each local version of a website. I'm thinking that I should do as you suggested. To change the script you provided to only run once a day should I set the interval to 24?

Comment: You could use `EVERY 1 DAY`, `EVERY 24 HOUR`, `EVERY 1440 MINUTE` ,`EVERY 86400 SECOND`.

Comment: What do you mean by local versions

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's critical to have the old rows at the very moment they turn 30 days old - a few seconds/minutes/hours delay will probably not hurt you at all. Therefore I'd remove old rows with some scheduled task/query run at some fixed interval.

Otherwise you'll end up running additional query for every page view that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the front end to display the data from the last 30 days. The delete at lesuire perhaps once a week depending on resources